# asp.net 4.5 mixing forms and windows authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-4.5

I'm starting a new ASP.NET 4.5 web forms application and one of the requirements is that there is the user to login with windows authentication if available or login using forms authentication if the user is not a member of the domain.

Additionally, there are 2 scenarios, above is the first one for if the user is on the internal network the other is if the user is accessing the application externally (https). In that case a prompt for user name and password should be able to authenticate either user type, be they a windows user or forms/application user.

Are these two options even possible? If so, how would I accomplish this?

I have combed the web for a few days now and everything I've seen so far is dated so I'm not sure if they are the best solution or if they will even work.

TIA

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968243/what-is-the-best-approach-for-mixed-mode-authentication-on-an-asp-net-intranet?rq=1